# I am trying to show roles releted to user on yajra datatable using laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am trying to show multiple roles related to the user on a Yajra data table.  But, roles are not showing related to the user.  I have shown data from the database in a JSON response as you can see below. How can I show the roles?

Note:- I am using spatie laravel permission https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v3/introduction

[image: datatable]

**JSON response**

```json
[
  {
    "id": 82,
    "name": "zubair",
    "type": 0,
    "email": "zubair@gmail.com",
    "email_verified_at": null,
    "status": 1,
    "created_at": "2020-12-25T03:29:19.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-12-25T03:29:19.000000Z",
    "roles": [
      {
        "id": 21,
        "name": "Designer",
        "guard_name": "web",
        "status": 1,
        "created_at": "2020-10-25T17:40:48.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-10-25T17:40:48.000000Z",
        "pivot": {
          "model_id": 82,
          "role_id": 21,
          "model_type": "App\\User"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 24,
        "name": "designer manager",
        "guard_name": "web",
        "status": 1,
        "created_at": "2020-12-25T02:58:36.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-12-25T02:58:36.000000Z",
        "pivot": {
          "model_id": 82,
          "role_id": 24,
          "model_type": "App\\User"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**user controller**

```
public function datatable()
  {
    $roles['roles']  = Role::where('name', '!=', 'super-admin')->get();
    $roles = User::with('roles')->where('type', '=', 0)->get();
       
    return DataTables::of($roles)->make(true);
  }
```

**jquery datatable**

```
var table = $('#datatable').DataTable({
          processing: true,
          serverSide: true,
          ajax: '{{route("user.datatable")}}',
          "columns": [
            { "data": "id", "defaultContent": "" },
            { "data": "name", "defaultContent": "" },
            { "data": "roles.name", "defaultContent": "" },
            { "data": "status", "defaultContent": "" },
            { "data": "id", "defaultContent": "" },
                  ],
          "columnDefs": [{
            "targets": 'no-sort',
            "orderable": false,
          },
```

Comment: How do Yajra  datatables differ from other datatables?  Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62455930/laravel-datatable-shows-role-name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to get the roles and modify it

**User Controller**

```
public function datatable()
{
    $roles = User::whereHas('roles', function ($query) {
        $query->where('roles.name', '!=', 'super-admin');
    })
    ->with('roles')
    ->where('type', '=', 0)
    ->get();

    $roles = $roles->transform(function ($item) {
        $item->role_names = $item->roles->pluck('name')->implode(', ');
        return $item;
    })->all();

    return DataTables::collection($roles)->toJson();
}
```

and in the Javascript you could do

```
var table = $('#datatable').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: '{{ route("user.datatable") }}',
    "columns": [
        { "data": "id", "defaultContent": "" },
        { "data": "name", "defaultContent": "" },
        { "data": "role_names", "defaultContent": ""},
        { "data": "status", "defaultContent": ""},
    ],
    "columnDefs": [{
        "targets": 'no-sort',
        "orderable": false,
    },
```